# Will a C++ program that compiles for MinGW on Windows work for GNU compiler on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compiler-construction, cmd

**Problem 1.** In my course, I am required to program in C++ which will be compiled/executed on a Linux machine. My professor tells me to use the GNU C++ compiler but it's been rather difficult obtaining it. I currently run a windows machine and I'm wondering if C++ program that compiles on MinGW (the compiler I use on my windows machine) will compile on the Linux machine that uses GNU.

In short: Will any of my MinGW compile(able) C++ programs on my Windows machine compile/work on a Linux machine using the GNU compiler?

If not, I will continue my attempts at obtaining GNU.

**Problem 2.** I've read [from http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_unpack_a_tar_file_in_windows ] that having MinGW installed allows me to use TAR via my command problem. However, my computer does not recognized tar commands. That is:

typing: tar cvf ...file names... into the CMD prompt yields 'tar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How or what exactly do I install to make it so that I can make TAR's via CMD prompt only? (I am aware of winzip, 9zip, etc but I prefer the CMD prompt)

Bear in mind that I've little experience outside of windows as of now. Thank you.

Comment: "MinGW" stands for "minimalistic **GNU** for Windows". Guess what. (Also, it's generally Windows that lacks standard and/or POSIX features, Linux is more likely to have them. So if you managed your code to compile it under Windows, and it's not Windows-specific, then you definitely have some hope.)

Comment: You might be better off with cygwin than mingw, or even better with a linux VM. The second question would be better suited for superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: infact... forget my answer, @DavidRodríguez-dribeas 's idea is much better :) ... just use cygwin (which has options to install the gnu compiler with it) and then do all your dev in that environment :)

Comment: Just install Linux on your machine. You'll learn a big lot, and you are following courses because you want to learn!

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1:
You might want to consider using virtualbox and installing a linux distribution.
At that point you can compile in the target environment. My 12 year old installed linux mint with a little direction and very little instruction.

Problem 2:
Might be solved by the solution to problem 1 :-)

Comment: I agree with all that too :) ... another option is: install virtual box (free) and install ubuntu (free) on that. Will probably take less then an hour or so :)

Comment: Or he might consider a dual boot machine; this has usually been my preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

problem 1: As long as you don't use any windows APIs or include any windows specific libraries then the chances are that it will compile under linux using GNU. MinGW is also a GNU derivitive :)

Problem 2: If you can't find a archive tool for windows you can always install cygwin on your windows machine. It basically allows you to use a linux style bash prompt (along with many features from linux that you can install including tar/untar).